# In the new Android Q Preview SDK compatible with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0

When I try to update my kotlin project to build against Android Q, I get

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  New Gradle Sync is not supported due to containing Kotlin modules using an unsupported plugin version
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Comment: Run gradle manually in the project folder with `--stacktrace `, like this `gradlew --stacktrace` or `gradlew --info`, and post the error here.

Comment: Android Q builds definitely work with Kotlin. The error message indicates that your plugin version is incorrect. In a typical Kotlin Android Studio project, that plugin version is defined in the `buildscript` closure in the top-level `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this was happening, but after build from command line, Android Studio isn't complaining anymore.  Didn't change the plugin version or anything else.